# Setting Up Boundaries of Integration

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the region in space bounded by the plane $z=0$ and above by $z=\frac{1}{4} -x^{2} - y^{2}$. We wish to set up the limit of integration using $\text{d}\rho\;\text{d}\phi\;\text{d}\theta$. The problem I am facing is that I can set it up using polar coordinates but to convert it to spherical of this order is quite challenging for me. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of it from a geometrical perspective before you think of the conversion. You have $\rho$ is the distance from the origin to any arbitrary point $\gamma$ on the surface of the paraboloid that is given by $(P) : z=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4}-x^{2}-y^{2}$. You should see that unlike the sphere, the distance between the origin and $\gamma$ is not fixed $\forall\gamma\in P$. Thus, to translate this as a mathematical argument, the lower bound of $\rho$ is clearly $0$ but the upper bound is the surface of the paraboloid which again is not fixed. Therefore, convert the equation of the paraboloid into spherical coordinates, we get that :
$$
z=\frac{1}{4}-x^{2}-y^{2}\implies\rho\cos(\phi)=\frac{1}{4}-\rho^{2}\sin^{2}(\phi)
$$
If it is not obvious to you that this is a quadratic equation (when treating $\phi$ as a constant), then rewrite it as follow :
$$
\rho^{2}\sin^{2}(\phi)+\rho\cos(\phi)-\frac{1}{4}=0
$$
This will yield to two distinct solutions :
$$
\rho_{1,2}=\frac{-\cos(\phi)\pm\sqrt{\cos^{2}(\phi)+\sin^{2}(\phi)}}{2\sin^{2}(\phi)}
$$
However, you are only allowed to have $\rho>0$ thus :
$$
\rho=\frac{-\cos(\phi)+\sqrt{\cos^{2}(\phi)+\sin^{2}(\phi)}}{2\sin^{2}(\phi)}=\boxed{\frac{1-\cos(\phi)}{2\sin^{2}(\phi)}}
$$
To find $\phi$, it is not bad at all since by setting $x=0$, we are able to project our surface onto the $zy$-plane and by sketching the region we will get $\boxed{\displaystyle 0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Hence, we obtain :
$$
\boxed{\displaystyle\int_{\displaystyle0}^{\displaystyle 2\pi}\displaystyle\int_{\displaystyle0}^{\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{\displaystyle0}^{\displaystyle\frac{1-\cos(\phi)}{2\sin^{2}(\phi)}}\rho^{2}\sin(\phi)\text{d}\rho\;\text{d}\phi\;\text{d}\theta}
$$